# Getting longitude and latitude

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, mapkit, core-location

I have experience crash of the app when using it in US. In all other countries same code is working. The crash is happening on line:

```
let latitude = String(format: "%.7f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
```

I really can't see what is the problem, specially cos is related to US and not to other counties. Any help will be very very much appreciate.

My UserLocation.swift looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

public class GPSLocation {

static let sharedInstance = GPSLocation()

//MARK: Public variables

public var intermediateLatitude: String?
public var intermediateLongitude: String?
public var intermediateCountry: String?
public var intermediateCity: String?
public var intermediateTimeZone: String?

//MARK: Get Longitude, Country Code and City name

func getGPSLocation(completition: @escaping () -> Void) {

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let locManager = manager
        var currentLocation: CLLocation!
        locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedAlways) {

            currentLocation = locManager.location

            if currentLocation != nil {
                // Get longitude & latitude
                let latitude = String(format: "%.7f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)
                let longitude = String(format: "%.7f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
                self.intermediateLatitude = latitude
                self.intermediateLongitude = longitude
                // debugPrint("Latitude:",latitude)
                // debugPrint("Longitude:",longitude)

                // Get local time zone GMT
                let localTimeZoneAbbreviation = TimeZone.current.abbreviation() ?? ""  // "GMT-2"
                let indexStartOfText = localTimeZoneAbbreviation.index(localTimeZoneAbbreviation.startIndex, offsetBy: 3) // 3
                let timeZone = localTimeZoneAbbreviation.substring(from: indexStartOfText) // "-2"
                self.intermediateTimeZone = timeZone
                // debugPrint("GMT:",timeZone)

                // Get Country code and City
                let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
                fetchCountryAndCity(location: location) { countryCode, city in
                    self.intermediateCountry = countryCode
                    self.intermediateCity = city
                    // debugPrint("Country code:",countryCode)
                    // debugPrint("City:",city)

                    completition()
                }
            } else {
                // Location is NIL
            }
        }
    }
    locManager.delegate = self // and conform protocol
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

//MARK: Find countryCode & City name from longitude & latitude

func fetchCountryAndCity(location: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (String, String) -> ()) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error)
        } else if let countryCode = placemarks?.first?.isoCountryCode,
            let city = placemarks?.first?.locality {
            completion(countryCode, city)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that `locManager.location` is not `nil` ?

Comment: Should i than wrap whole block in if locManager.location is not nil from //Get longitude and latitude till end of completition() in that if statement...?

Comment: First isolate the problem. If locManager.location is nil then the problem is unrelated to String(format:...). Then search for "CLLocationManager location is nil", there are already lots of Q&A's about that.

Comment: @FanbandTest do you want solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check location in delegate method

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
          manager.stopUpdatingLocation() // if you dont want continuously update

            currentLocation = manager.location
         let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    fetchCountryAndCity(location: location) { countryCode, city in
        self.intermediateCountry = countryCode
        self.intermediateCity = city
        // debugPrint("Country code:",countryCode)
        // debugPrint("City:",city)

        completition()
    }
   }
```

**And set delegate**

```
locManager.delegate = self // and conform protocol 
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

Comment: I'm beginner in swift, so sorry for asking... If I change whole class (code) with your code... is it going to send location constantly? I need to pass from this class results from long, lat, countryCode and city, only once to other class. Update only when I call it from other class.

Comment: if you dont want continuously then you can stop updating of cllocationManage in this method **didUpdateLocations**.

Comment: So I should put function from your answer in AppDelegate.swift in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions..? or in ViewController in which I need results from func getGPSLocation..?

Comment: you can put anywhere you want . it is depends on your requirement .

Comment: it is wrong you can't add delegate function inside of function.